# Proof of a solution of Klein-Gordon equation with Killing vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, field-theory, vector-fields, klein-gordon-equation

In this (very good) notes: http://people.physics.tamu.edu/pope/geomlec.pdf it is set as an exercise to proof that if $u_i$ solves the Klein-Gordon equation:

$$(\Box -m^2 )u_i = 0$$

then you can proof, appealing to the properties of the Killing vectors, that the Killing vector $K^\mu \partial_\mu$ also solves

$$(\Box -m^2 )K^\mu \partial_\mu u_i = 0$$

and that the key point is to prove that $\Box(K^\mu \partial_\mu u_i ) = K^\mu \partial_\mu\Box u_i$

Honestly, I don't get with the key. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just use Eq (5.52) to write $\square K_{\mu} = -R_{\mu\nu}K^{\nu}$, and then manipulate everything from there?

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Yes, I thought in using that equality, but I can't get anything from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is a Killing vector, it satisfies
$$
\nabla_\mu K_\nu  + \nabla_\nu K_\mu = 0 \quad \implies \quad \nabla^\mu K_\mu = 0 ~. 
$$
Another property we will need can be proved by acting on the above euqation with $\nabla^\nu$. We find
\begin{align}
\Box K_\mu 
&= - \nabla^\nu \nabla_\mu K_\nu \\
&= [ \nabla_\mu ,  \nabla_\nu ]K^\nu \\
&= R^\nu{}_{\lambda\mu\nu} K^\lambda \\
&= - R_{\mu\nu} K^\nu~. 
\end{align}
Now, we have
$$
( \nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu - m^2 ) K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi = \Box K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi +  2  \nabla^\mu   K^\nu \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi +  K^\nu  \nabla^\mu  \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi - m^2 K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi ~. 
$$
Note
$$
 \nabla^\mu   K^\nu \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi 
=\frac{1}{2} ( \nabla^\mu   K^\nu + \nabla^\nu   K^\mu )  \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi = 0 ~,
$$
and
\begin{align}
K^\nu  \nabla^\mu  \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi 
&= K^\nu  \nabla^\mu   \nabla_\nu  \nabla_\mu \phi \\
&= K^\nu \nabla_\nu  \Box  \phi + K^\nu  [ \nabla^\mu  , \nabla_\nu ]  \nabla_\mu \phi \\
&= m^2 K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi + K^\mu R_{\mu\nu} \nabla^\mu \phi  ~. 
\end{align}
Putting all this together, we find
\begin{align}
( \nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu - m^2 ) K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi 
&= \Box K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi   +  m^2 K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi + K^\mu R_{\mu\nu} \nabla^\mu \phi  - m^2 K^\nu \nabla_\nu \phi  \\
&= 0 ~.
\end{align}
QED.

Comment: I have a couple of questions if you don't mind: why are you writing the Killing vector as $K^\mu \nabla_\mu$ instead of $K^\mu \partial_\mu$? And the $\Box$ operator over the Killing vector shouldn't be only $(\Box K^\mu )\partial_\mu \phi + K^\mu \Box(\partial_\mu \phi)$?

Comment: When acting on a scalar field, $\nabla_\mu \phi = \partial_\mu \phi$. $\Box = \nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu$ so it is a square of a derivative operator and it does not distribute in the way that you write. Is $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} (fg) = \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} g + f \frac{d^2g}{dx^2}$?????

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the square nature of the $\Box$ operator.